# Generalization of invariance of domain

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose I say a topological space $X$ has the *invariance of domain property* iff $S \subset X$ is open as soon as $S$ is homeomorphic to an open set of $X$.

We know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has this property. What other spaces have this property?

Comment: I must be missing something in your question.  Every topological space $X$ has the property that $S \subset X$ is open iff it is homeomorphic to an open subset of $X$.  Am I interpreting your wording incorrectly?

Comment: @MichaelHarrison Why do you say that? The proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not elementary.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your wording, then what you have written is trivially true for every topological space $X$.  Maybe you want to give $X$ the *invariance of domain property* if the following condition holds: for every open $S \subset X$, every injective continuous map $f : S \to X$ is an open map.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison Can you prove it, please?

Comment: If $S \subset X$ is open, it is homeomorphic to an open set in $X$ (itself) by the identity map.  If $S$ is homeomorphic to an open set $T$, $f:S \to T$, then $f$ is a continuous map so $S = f^{-1}(T)$ is open.

Comment: I'm with Eric, in generality is false. Consider For example $[0,1]\cup [2,4)$. Then $[2,3]$ is not open but homeomorphic to an open set.

Comment: $S$ is open in $S$, not in $X$... @MichaelHarrison

Comment: ha...... yeah..

Comment: You have such theorems for manifolds. I suspect you should have similar theorems for homology manifolds. Of course we don't have them for manifolds with boundary.

Comment: Yes, the same holds for homology manifolds.

Comment: More generally, each pseudomanifold satisfies the invariance of domain property.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21512/is-there-domain-invariance-for-alexandrov-spaces